# Where are the hidden videos and pictures from Camfiler's VS and/or PS apps?

Tags: file-system, encryption

In Camfiler's PS and VS programs where are my hidden videos and pictures on my SD card for when I back up my card to my computer?

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden"?  What hides them?

Comment: VS and PS are video and photo encrypter apps that make password protected areas on your phone to "hide" sensitive material. The only problem is that you can't back up those pictures and videos while they're hidden and there's no way to batch unlock everything you hid. Even if you did they would all go back to the date they were added, which when you have a lot of media makes them very difficult to find.